# Can i wear mens clothes?

Tags: halal-haram, clothing

I'm a young Muslim women living in a non Muslim country and have been struggling with what to wear recently. Usually I have and do wear mens clothes from siblings or I just buy them for reasons of modesty and comfort. I did not think much of it at first as it isnt noticeable that they are exclusively mens clothes. I have tried doing research on cross dressing for women in the quran however I'm not sure it's the right search as it is absolutely clear I am a girl, still however it is usually unclear as it mostly talks about men dressing like women and not the other way around.

Comment: Salam and welcime to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam to learn more about our site and model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help]. Actually there's a difference on where and in what environment you may wear clothes. Among the most important things is that clothes you as a girl can wear don't display the shape of your body for foreigners.

Answer (score 1):

Narrated Ibn 'Abbas:
"The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) cursed the women who imitate men and the men who imitate women."

(Tirmidhi:2784)

Abu Hurairah (May Allah be pleased with him) said:
The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) cursed a man who puts on the dress of women, and a woman who puts on the dress of men.

(Abu Dawood:  4098, Riyad as-Salihin 1632)

Comment: Just citing evidences without explanation isn't answering the question correctly. [As evidences are not self-explanatory](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1475/do-evidences-speak-for-themselves). What is the accepted interpretation of these ahadith? OP didn't display any intention to imitate men!